# How to create individual objects and list them in an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

My current array is not creating individual objects as I would like it to. My data is in the following format:

```
["1434100866", "599.0", "1434100870", "349.0", "1434100863", "233.0", "1434100849", "269.0", "1434100857", "682.0", "1434100862", "248.0", "1434100865", "342.0", "1434100848", "960.0", "1434100853", "270.0", "1434100850", "253.0"]
```

I would like my data to be in the following format:

```
[[item1, item2],[item1, item2],[item1, item2], ...];
```

Here's my code:

```
        var dataArray = new Array();
        @foreach (var record in Model)
        {
            @:dataArray.push("@record.date", "@record.rate");
        }        
        console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: Well it does because I'm using mvc 4 view for this example. I put it the C# category because I figured maybe it was an issue with razor script syntax, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `push` a new array, not new values. Do this:

```
var dataArray = new Array();
@foreach (var record in Model)
{
    @:dataArray.push(["@record.date", "@record.rate"]);
}        
console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is how the data comes out now: dataArray.push(["1434100866", "599.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100870", "349.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100863", "233.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100849", "269.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100857", "682.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100862", "248.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100865", "342.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100848", "960.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100853", "270.0"]);
            dataArray.push(["1434100850", "253.0"]);

Comment: No. This is correct. It turned out that my datatypes were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a=["1434100866", "599.0", "1434100870", "349.0", "1434100863", "233.0", "1434100849", "269.0", "1434100857", "682.0", "1434100862", "248.0", "1434100865", "342.0", "1434100848", "960.0", "1434100853", "270.0", "1434100850", "253.0"];
var b = a.reduce(function (res, el, i) {
    if (i % 2) {
        res[res.length - 1].push(el);
    } else {
        res.push([el]);
    }
    return res;
}, []);
 document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(b, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```